# Font looks differ between Storybook and the main app

Tags: browser, fonts, storybook

Fonts look different between Storybook and the main application (Webpack's dev server). Letters seem to take less space width-wise, and they seem bolder.

Their computed styles are the same (compared by eye in Chrome's DevTools). They also both are wrapped in the same components, only the store provided to Redux differs (houses only 4-5 irrelevant variables).

What could possibly be making Storybook look different?

Main application:

[image: Main application]

Storybook:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @lonewarrior556 No, I don't think so. However, it could be simply a different font, you see on the screenshots that some letters are visibly different. Make sure to load your fonts in storybook's `.storybook/preview-head.html` (https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-rendering) (unless you load them via JS)

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue. I'm setting the font to Arial to avoid the chance of a font being missing, and even then the text rendering looks different. I'm seeing it on MacBook with a retina display btw.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and turned out it was because of the following css property that I had to also add to the storybook global.css:

```css
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wan7n.png)